# react-native-web module with native extension not found even though I'm targeting it in webpack

Tags: webpack, react-native-web

I have a RN project to which I'm adding react native web. I "ejected" from react-scripts and tweaked the webpack `babel-loader` config to target `node_modules` and `ios.js` extension files

```
// webpack.config.js
test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx|ios.js)$/,
include: [paths.appSrc, paths.appNodeModules],
loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
```

I'm importing [`@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication) and getting the following error in the terminal:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './AppleButton' in '/home/goldy/apps/bites-native/node_modules/@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/lib'
```

In the code of this package, there's no `AppleButton.js`, but there is `AppleButton.ios.js`, which I'm targeting in my config.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with adding `.ios.js` to the extensions list in `webpack.config.js`, under `resolve.extensions`